# Reference another property in application.properties and have it recognized by Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, properties

I think I've seen in some tutorial, which I can't now remember, that you can have a property in `application.properties` reference another property. Furthermore, Intellij will understand what you're doing (make that placeholder clickable and take you to the referenced property and that kind of things).

Something as follows:

```
my.prop.abs=example.com
my.prop.rel=${my.prop.abs}/about
```

I just can't find the placeholder to use. Is this possible at all?

Comment: That was it and for me it works fine on IJ Ultimate 2016. What version are you using and also, did you [configure your spring facet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/enabling-spring-support.html) in your project?